# How to add fonts in InDesign when packaging?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using custom fonts in my InDesign document and when I use **File->Package** I check checkboxes *"Copy fonts"* and *"Include Fonts and Links..."*. But in the new folder no fonts are found.
I'm using FontExpert to temporarily install those fonts.
What may be the problem?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Graphic Design. This is an Adobe tech support question, which is off-topic for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the fonts are temporarily installed. There may also be an issue with the permissions in the fonts themselves, which may not allow copying, but I'm betting that the font manager is the source of the missing fonts.

Install the fonts for real, then package the document.

You can also place the font files in the `Document Fonts` folder yourself. There's nothing magical about that folder. When InDesign opens the INDD file, it will activate any fonts it finds there if they are called for by the document.

Answer (score 0):

Using a font manager will not work for Windows and InDesign. Windows is not very accommodating for those in publishing. You can see when you go to package fonts are listed as "incomplete". Fonts should be installed (added) to the fonts folder on the C drive for them to package. Mac has never had an issue with this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).